# ComponentDidMount not firing in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have suddenly run into this problem in my app, the componentDidMount does not work when loading the page and I get typescript error due to the information not being loaded. It was working fine yesterday and the day before and now I have no idea  what I did wrong. I have 4 api calls for the method GET, it's only for the GET method. Is there a way to make the component work again ?  I have no idea why it behaves this way.

```js
class adminView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Users: [],
      Movies: [],
      Comments: [],
      Ratings: [],
      message: null,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.reloadObjectiveList().then((r) => console.log("result" + r));
    this.reloadUserList().then((r) => {
      console.log("result" + r);
    });
  }

  async reloadUserList() {
    await UserApiService.fetchUsers().then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        Users: res.data.result,
      });
    });
  }
  async reloadObjectiveList() {
    await UserApiService.fetchUsers().then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({
        Users: res.data.result,
      });
    });

    await MovieApiService.fetchMovies().then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        Movies: res.data.result,
      });
    });

    await CommentApiService.fetchComments().then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.result);
      this.setState({
        Comments: res.data.result,
      });
    });
    await RatingApiService.fetchrating().then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.result);
      this.setState({
        Ratings: res.data.result,
      });
    });
  }

  deleteUsersComments(ObjectiveId) {
    CommentApiService.deleteComment(ObjectiveId).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ message: "Objective deleted successfully." });
      this.setState({
        Comments: this.state.Comments.filter(
          (Objective) => Objective.username !== ObjectiveId
        ),
      });
    });
  }
  deleteUsersRatingss(ObjectiveId) {
    RatingApiService.deleterating(ObjectiveId).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ message: "Objective deleted successfully." });
      this.setState({
        Ratings: this.state.Ratings.filter(
          (Objective) => Objective.username !== ObjectiveId
        ),
      });
    });
  }
  deleteMovies(ObjectiveId) {
    MovieApiService.deleteTourist(ObjectiveId).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ message: "Objective deleted successfully." });
      this.setState({
        Movies: this.state.Movies.filter(
          (Objective) => Objective.imdb_id !== ObjectiveId
        ),
      });
    });
  }
  deleteUsers(ObjectiveId) {
    UserApiService.deleteTourist(ObjectiveId).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ message: "Objective deleted successfully." });
      this.setState({
        Movies: this.state.Movies.filter(
          (Objective) => Objective.username !== ObjectiveId
        ),
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { details, loading } = this.props;

    return (
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <Paper className={styles.paper}>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Hello ADMIN
          </Typography>
          <hr />
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Users:
          </Typography>

          <div className="card-list">
            {console.log(this.state.Users)}
            {this.state.Users.map((item) => (
              <CardUsers item={item} key={item.username} />
            ))}
          </div>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>UserFirstName</TableCell>
                <TableCell>UserLastName</TableCell>
                <TableCell>UserEmail</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {this.state.Users.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.username}>
                  <TableCell align="center">{row.firstName}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">{row.lastName}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="center">{row.email}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell
                    align="center"
                    onClick={() => this.deleteUsers(row.username)}
                  >
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
          <hr />
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            MOVIES
          </Typography>
          <hr />
          <div className="card-list">
            <Card item={this.state.Movies} />
          </div>

          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Comments
          </Typography>
          <hr />

          <hr />
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>UserId</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Comment</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {this.state.Comments.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.username}>
                  <TableCell align="center">{row.username}</TableCell>
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableCell>MovieID</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Comment</TableCell>
                  </TableHead>

                  <TableBody>
                    {row.commentsList.map((row2) => (
                      <TableRow key={row2.id}>
                        <TableCell align="center">{row2.movieID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="center">{row2.comment}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell
                          align="center"
                          onClick={() => this.deleteUsersComments(row2)}
                        >
                          <DeleteIcon />
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>

          <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
            Ratings
          </Typography>
          <hr />

          <hr />
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>UserId</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Ratings</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {this.state.Ratings.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.username}>
                  <TableCell align="center">{row.username}</TableCell>
                  <TableHead>
                    <TableCell>MovieID</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>Rating</TableCell>
                  </TableHead>

                  <TableBody>
                    {row.ratingsList.map((row2) => (
                      <TableRow key={row2.id}>
                        <TableCell align="center">{row2.movieID}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="center">{row2.rating}</TableCell>
                        <TableCell
                          align="center"
                          onClick={() => this.deleteUsersRatingss(row2)}
                        >
                          <DeleteIcon />
                        </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                    ))}
                  </TableBody>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </Paper>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(withStyles(styles)(adminView));
```

Comment: How are you so sure it doesn't get called, have you tried putting a console.log before the reloadObjectiveList function call to see if it gets called?

Comment: Yes, I did placed one inside ComponentdidMount and one  outside in the state, thee one from the state was the only one to get called

Comment: I did not read all the code and even tried to understand it : i just hardly recommand you to split all this in components and external functions (like redux thunk actions) in order to deal with all the async method you are using. I am pretty sure that once you'll do that, you should understand better whats going on here.